# nested expandable grids - inner grids won't collapse and expand properly

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am trying to modify the first ExtJS example which can be found [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.0/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html)

to my needs.
I want an expandable grid in which clicking on a specific item, opens another expandable grid.

I have tried introducing these changes to the existing code and encountered the following problem:

1. In each inner grid, the rows appear with a minus sign next to them when the grid is loaded
2. When clicking on a row in the inner grid it would open but when clicking again, it won't collapse.
3. I've noticed a "mysterious" connection between the rows of each of the inner grid and the rows of the outer grid - double clicking on the second row in the inner grid, for example, will cause a collapse/expand reaction in the second row in the outer grid (but no influence on the inner grid after it is expanded).

Where did I get it wrong or misused the code?

Here is my code:

```
var urlObject = Ext.urlDecode(document.location.search);
var request_url = 'my_url';
var request_state = 'my_state';

// row expander
var expander = new Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander({
    tpl : new Ext.Template(
        '<p>{layer_name} --- under construction!!!</p>'
    )
});

expander.on('expand', function(rowExp, rec, body, rowIndex) {

    var inner_expander = new Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander({
        tpl : new Ext.Template(
            '<p>under construction!!!</p>'
        )
    });


    var sub_layer_store = new Ext.data.JsonStore ({
        url: request_url,
        fields: ['sub_layer_name'],
        root: 'sub_layer_names',
        baseParams: {
            _state: request_state,
            _action: 'get_sub_layer_names',
            layer_name: rec.data.layer_name
        }
    });

    var sub_layer_grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: sub_layer_store,
        cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
            defaults: {
                width: 20,
                sortable: true
            },
            columns: [
                inner_expander,
                {header: "Sub-Layer", width: 40, dataIndex: 'sub_layer_name'}
            ]
        }),
        viewConfig: {
            forceFit:true
        },        
        width: 1100,
        height: 200,
        plugins: inner_expander,
        collapsible: true,
        animCollapse: false,
        title: 'Sub-Layers information',
        iconCls: 'icon-grid',
        renderTo: body
    });

    //load the sub grid
    sub_layer_grid.store.load();

});

var layers_store = new Ext.data.JsonStore ({
    url: request_url,
    fields: ['layer_name'],
    root: 'layer_names',
    baseParams: {
        _state: request_state,
        _action: 'get_layer_names'
    }
});


var layers_grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: layers_store,
    cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        defaults: {
            width: 20,
            sortable: true
        },
        columns: [
            expander,
            {header: "Layer", width: 40, dataIndex: 'layer_name'}
        ]
    }),
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit:true
    },        
    width: 1200,
    height: 500,
    plugins: expander,
    collapsible: true,
    animCollapse: false,
    title: 'Layers information',
    iconCls: 'icon-grid'
});


Ext.onReady(function(){

    var el = document.getElementById('my_container');

    layers_grid.store.load();
    layers_grid.render(el);

});
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: I gave up on this and changed my code to work with Ext.tree.TreePanel, Ext.tree.TreeLoader and Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode. It might not be as elegant but at least it works...

Comment: TreeGrid does not have a source code and it also looks like the number and type of fields in the inner grid needs to match the outer... I did find this lovely example (did not have a chance to try it as I settled for TreePanel and it does the job just fine:) but it might help people who actually read this post: http://mikhailstadnik.com/ext/examples/nested-grid.htm also - if only one layer of inner grid is needed then the above code works fine...

Answer (score 1):

The only reason for your  3rd problem is you are not mentioning id to grid and following that ..
By default extjs uses row and column index to do collapse and expand. So the 2nd row's row index of inner grid will be same as 2nd row's row index of outer grid..
May be the same reason for other two problms.
If anybody needs sourxe code let me know will attach a sample .

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I no longer have access to the platform that code was part of so I have no way of checking your suggestion so this is why I do not mark your answer as accepted... I appreciate your effort and thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Having another expandable grid is complex (for the users). You may try having one border panel with Tree on the left region and the details on the right region (if applicable on your design).